# Как переместить определенные столбцы из одной таблицы в другую в SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравстуйте! У меня есть две таблицы `books` и `books_new.` Я через `inner join` объединил два столбца и получил

| name | name_new |
| --- | --- |
| Властелин Колец | Властелин Колец |
| Утраченный Символ | Утраченный Символ |
| Гарри Поттер | Гарри Поттер |

но как скопировать столбец `code_id` из таблицы `books` в `books_new`

| name | code_id |
| --- | --- |
| Властелин Колец | 05001479 |
| Утраченный Символ | 00955448 |
| Гарри Поттер | 66524878 |

чтобы в итоге я получил такой исход и чтобы каждый айди подходил к своей строке

| name_new | code_id |
| --- | --- |
| Властелин Колец | 05001479 |
| Утраченный Символ | 00955448 |
| Гарри Поттер | 66524878 |

```
select b.name, n.name_new, b.code_id  FROM books b
  inner join books_new n on b.name = n.name_new
```

Comment: Покажите Ваш запрос с джоинами.

Comment: @РустамАлиев извиняюсь, сделал поправки в вопросе. мой код select b.name, n.name_new, b.code_id  FROM books b
  inner join books_new n on b.name = n.name_new

Answer (score 1):

используйте update+join

```
UPDATE nb
    SET nb.code_id = b.code_id
FROM books_new AS nb
INNER JOIN books AS b ON b.name = nb.name
```

Comment: не могли бы объяснить, почему вначале bn?

Comment: @frehsmanboy очевидно `nb`, опечатка

Comment: а как убрать дублирование строк? Distinct не работает

Comment: @frehsmanboy а откуда появляется дублирование? одинаковые названия книг в старой таблице?

Comment: да, там помимо code_id есть другие значения. Например переводы от других издательств

Comment: так напишите нужные условия в JOIN